# Combining two SUMIF statements using two ranges

Tags: excel, sumifs

[image]

I have two data cells, for today and previous day for products
I also have a cell that states whether the product is eligible or ineligible

I'd like to sum sales for today, IF product is ineligible today, BUT was eligible yesterday. is this possible in excel without using VBA?

I was playing with combining two SUMIF statements but not sure if this would work

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your data structure? Show us some sample data and the expected output given that data. `SUMIFS` is fine here but don't know the data structure so you can't really get an answer beyond that given lack of other relevant details

Comment: Yes. You can achieve this with `SUMIFS`

Comment: i have now added an image.

Comment: How can I use SUMIFS if i need to filter through two data ranges?

Comment: Based on your pic, you have "eligible" as if it would apply to all dates for that row. How would this look for occasions as described in your question?

Comment: Hi, I have added a second picture that will hopefully answer your question

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the Pivot Table itself. Probably you will need to calculate something in source range before creating Pivot Table.

Comment: "How can I use SUMIFS if i need to filter through two data ranges" >> do : `=sumifs(<range1>,<conditions>)+sumifs(<range2>,<SameConditionsAsRange1>)`